# Descriptive programming is not working in different machine for Webbutton

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I want to user descriptive programming to identify object in a web application in chrome. But I found that my scripts is work in laptop but not remote desktop.

Noted that Chrome, UFT chrome addin, UFT are using same version and already reset to factory setting. Both are using same object repository.

I tried many times:

Case1:

```
On error resume next

Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("class:=mat- 
calendar-period-button mat-button").Click
Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("disabled:=0").Click
Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("height:=40").Click
Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("html tag:=BUTTON").Click
Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("innerhtml:=<span class=""mat-button-wrapper"">FRI JUN 21 2019<div class=""mat-calendar-arrow""></div></span><div class=""mat-button-ripple mat-ripple"" md-ripple="""" ng-reflect-trigger=""\[object HTMLButtonElement\]"" ng-reflect-centered=""false"" ng-reflect-disabled=""false""></div><div class=""mat-button-focus-overlay""></div>").Click
Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("acc_name:=Change to year view").Click
Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("innertext:=FRI JUN 21 2019").Click
Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("type:=submit").Click
Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("width:=148").Click
Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("name:=FRI JUN 21 2019").Click
Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("outerhtml:=<button class=""mat-calendar-period-button mat-button"" md-button="""" aria-label=""Change to year view""><span class=""mat-button-wrapper"">FRI JUN 21 2019<div class=""mat-calendar-arrow""></div></span><div class=""mat-button-ripple mat-ripple"" md-ripple="""" ng-reflect-trigger=""\[object HTMLButtonElement\]"" ng-reflect-centered=""false"" ng-reflect-disabled=""false""></div><div class=""mat-button-focus-overlay""></div></button>").Click
Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("outertext:=FRI JUN 21 2019").Click
Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("value:=FRI JUN 21 2019").Click
Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("width:=148").Click
Browser("Br_eServices").Page("Pg_Claimsubmission").WebButton("y:=398","x:=418").Click



On error goto 0
```

In VM, all scripts is saying:
"Cannot identify the object "[ WebButton ]" (of class WebButton).
Verify that this object's properties match an object currently displayed in your application."

Case2:

```
Browser("FWD").Page("FWD").WebButton("xpath:=//DIV[3]/DIV[2]/MD-DATEPICKER-CONTENT[1]/MD-CALENDAR[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/BUTTON[1]","type:=submit").Click
```

Laptop and VM both working

Case3: Use object repository

```
Browser("FWD").Page("FWD").WebButton("Change to year view").Click
```

Laptop and VM both working

This is the object properties from object spy:

```
"Class Name:=WebButton",
"abs_x:=418",               
"abs_y:=469",                       
"acc_name:=Change to year view",
"class:=mat-calendar-period-button mat-button",
"disabled:=0",
"height:=40",
"html id:=",
"html tag:=BUTTON",
"innerhtml:=<span class=""mat-button-wrapper"">FRI JUN 21 2019<div class=""mat-calendar-arrow""></div></span><div class=""mat-button-ripple mat-ripple"" md-ripple="""" ng-reflect-trigger=""\[object HTMLButtonElement\]"" ng-reflect-centered=""false"" ng-reflect-disabled=""false""></div><div class=""mat-button-focus-overlay""></div>",
"innertext:=FRI JUN 21 2019",
"name:=FRI JUN 21 2019",
"outerhtml:=<button class=""mat-calendar-period-button mat-button"" md-button="""" aria-label=""Change to year view""><span class=""mat-button-wrapper"">FRI JUN 21 2019<div class=""mat-calendar-arrow""></div></span><div class=""mat-button-ripple mat-ripple"" md-ripple="""" ng-reflect-trigger=""\[object HTMLButtonElement\]"" ng-reflect-centered=""false"" ng-reflect-disabled=""false""></div><div class=""mat-button-focus-overlay""></div></button>",
"outertext:=FRI JUN 21 2019",
"role:=",
"title:=",
"type:=submit",
"value:=FRI JUN 21 2019",
"visible:=True",
"width:=148",
"x:=418",
"xpath:=//DIV\[3\]/DIV\[2\]/MD-DATEPICKER-CONTENT\[1\]/MD-CALENDAR\[1\]/DIV\[1\]/DIV\[1\]/BUTTON\[1\]",
"y:=398"
```

I expect case 1 will also success in VM. My question is: Why fail?

Comment: I would first check the Object properties in the OR for `Browser("Br_eServices")`. Always try to highlight Browser().Page() when you hit this kind of issue to make sure the OR is pointing to the right browser.

Comment: I guess you should have the same issue with all the line where ever you are using `Browser("Br_eServices")`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, Browser("Br_eServices") is same as Browser("FWD"), I just rename and forget to update when I copying

Comment: Highlight is fine but the issue still happening

Comment: Are you sure the `acc_name` and `type` of the object are the same on both computers?

Comment: Yes, it is a web application, it has same properties observed by object spy

Comment: Ok, can you please check the chrome versions. And also try using the xpath/OR in the case 1 to isolate the issue.

Comment: Hi supputuri, ok, I updated case1, follow those object properties. And I found that except xpath, other descriptive programming is not working in my VM